# PHP header Location перенаправляет на предыдущую страницу

Tags: php, url, header, location

Вместо того что бы перенаправить на новый url

```
// Заходим на https://domain1.ru/link/
header("Location: https://domain2.ru/);
```

```
// https://domain2.ru/
header("Location: https://domain1.ru/);
```

Но редирект происходит обратно на https://domain1.ru/link/

Comment: что значит: обратно? если "всё равно редиректит на старый url", то может кеш шалит? создайте новую страницу(с другим адресом), и посмотрите переадресацию на ней - если всё норм - чистите кеш.

Comment: @Yakoffka не думаю что дело в кэше

Comment: хорошо. но вопрос-то переформулировать можете? Что в Вашем понимании "предыдущая страница"? какой блок кода используете: первый или второй?

Comment: @Yakoffka
Да конечно:
1) Захожу на сайт domain1.ru/link - в этой директорий отрабатывает редирект на
domain2.ru/link2
2) После того как попал domain2.ru/link2 - этой директорий отрабатывает редирект  на
domain1.ru/ 
Но проблема в том что перейдя на domain1.ru/link меня возвращает обратно сюда же domain1.ru/link, почему меня возвращает на domain1.ru/link, если редирект должен перенаправить domain1.ru/

Comment: Хмм... Хитро! Уверены, что переадресация вообще происходит? Попробуйте перейти по адресу "domain2.ru/link2" - куда Вас перекинет?